# Global Customized View for Document Libraries in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

In Sharepoint document library, when we create a new document library, the default view is 'All Document'. This one:

[image]

We can make a custom view from **View > Create View** (at the upper right corner of document library view). I created a new standard view and named it 'Chromed View'. I edited it, then I saw that this view only applied on current document library:

[image]

The other document libraries cannot use this view.

I develop a system that triggers document library creation from CRM (the document library's view from CRM Iframe is using that chromed view). The creation itself went well, I can create document library using Sharepoint web services. But I still cannot apply a custom view automatically for that newly created doc lib.

My question is, can we make a view that is global (not in one document library only) so that we can use that global view for any document library.

Thanks b4 for any opinion :)

Answer (score 4):

You could also create a new custom document library type, with the view embedded in it.  Whenever a new library is created from the new doc lib type, it will get the new view.

This is still a not truly "global" view, and you may have the same problems if the view gets changed (the view won't be updated on document libraries that have been created with previous versions of the view).

Comment: nice suggestion :D I made that doc lib as a template, then tried creating doc lib from that template. It had the view I wanted! Thanks :D And now I have to find out how to create doc lib from the template by code, using the web services. If it is applicable, your suggestion is the solution I need :D

Comment: http://andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/02/08/A-Quicker-Way-to-Create-Custom-SharePoint-List-Templates.aspx

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to create a feature with an event receiver. When a user creates a list, you can check if the list is of the proper type (101), and then add new views to it. The feature could also add this view to existing document libraries on activation. Shouldn't be too much of an effort.
The view is not truly global. As list definitions are duplicated for each instance, there are no such thing as a global view (afaik) in WSS. We could all hope that views are a part of content type in the next version.

Comment: I'm still newbie in Sharepoint, so I'll google more about event receiver :D But, if the view itself isn't a global one, can it be applied to the new doc lib? I'm not asking about the doc lib creation. As for the doc lib creation is triggered from CRM plugin. How to make a view that is global?

Comment: Its not truly global, the view would be added to new document libraries as they are created, but changes to the view would not update document libraries that are using a previous version (without extra coding).

Answer (score 1):

To globally change all document libraries and to change all existing libraries you need to edit the XSLT file that is in the XSL folder in layours/templates

There are a couple of them in there but these are how all the libraries are generated with this u can basically specify how a default"" library would look.  Make sure to make a backup for these files though.  Also creating a new content type and copying these xlts to a different file name and then linking your content type to these instead could also be a solution so when a user creates a new library using ur content type you can make sure that they are created in a way that you want.