# How to make global views in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, view, sharepoint-2007, survey

I have a SharePoint site, where I need to locate different kinds of surveys, to divide them into different quick launches: Like, if I have Gardening, Painting and ext. quick launches I want surveys about gardening to be in Gardening launch, about painting in Painting launch and so on.

I decided to create a list ("Surveys List"), where will be all this surveys that user creates. List has a column - genre (column type: choice).
What I want is to create global views to do next: All surveys with gardening genre put into Gardening view , paintings in Painting and so on. I did views, which was visible in just "Surveys List" view. Of course, making with global views work is not done, mission is not accomplished.

As I'm really new in SharePoint probably there is So many better ways to do all that stuff, which I don't know. If anybody knows how to make global views or solve this problem, please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify - what do you mean by "Globals View"?

Comment: By "Global" I mean that I want to create view, which is visible in whole site not in just specific list. I Saw someone had kinda same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527209/global-customized-view-for-document-libraries-in-sharepoint). There was solution to create custom document library type, but it's not possible for surveys (I guess)

Comment: There is no such thing as a global view in sp - a view is always tied to one list. You can create an identical view on another list but its just a copy.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out.. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ryan you should post that as an answer so author can accept the answer in case if someone needs the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "global view" in SharePoint - a view is always tied to one list.

You can create an identical view on another list but its just a copy.