# Using the same custom view across web parts in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, view, sharepoint-2013

I have created a custom view to display data through a web part.

I'm looking to use this same custom view across different web parts, essentially creating a custom view with a global scope.

I've seen this article about attempting such a thing:

- [How to make global views in SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570189/how-to-make-global-views-in-sharepoint)

Is there not a way to achieve this in Sharepoint's settings? I'm looking for a way to bypass having to re-create each list manually.

Any help is always appreciated. Thankyou for your time!

Answer (score 0):

For lists already created, it isn't possible to re-use views through the browser interface. It is possible, though, to programmatically add the same view definition to existing lists through PowerShell or .NET.